# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) in the table that might be too wide for the page

Tags: tables, errors, unit-of-measure

I want to create following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{units}

\begin{document} 

    \begin{table*}[t]
        \small
        \begin{tabular}{ |l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c| }
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.9in}}{ }&
        \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Factor level}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.9in}}{Output} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{ABS-UTS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{ABS-THETA MIN} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{ABS-THETA MAX} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{ABS-Sa MIN} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{ABS-Sa max} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{PLA-UTS} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{PLA-THETA MIN} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{PLA-THETA MAX} &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}}{PLA-Sa MIN}&
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{0.35in}|}{PLA-Sa max}\\
        \hline
        Nozzle temperature ($ ^{\circ} $ C) & 3 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \hline
        Deposition speed  (\( \frac{\textrm{mm}}{\textrm{s}} \)) & 
        3 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
        \hline
        Layer heigh (mm) & 
        3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
            \caption{Configurations for single lap experimental investigation}
            \label{tab:results}
            \paperwidth
    \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Why am I getting these errors while the .tex file still compiles:

```
./paper.tex:317: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.317 \end{table*}

./paper.tex:317: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.317 \end{table*}
```

Also, is it possible to increase the fourth line height?

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete but small document with your table (beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`).

Comment: Edited - you should be able to compile the code now.

Comment: Unrelated, but nowadays you should use the siunitx package to typeset units

Comment: And what is that `\paperwidth` doing at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me is simpler to rewrite your table code fragment than search for errors. They can be hidden in superfluous use of `\multicolumn{1}{p{<length>}}{...}` (why you not define columns type on this way?), or in spurious `\paperwidth` at end of `table` environment etc.

For your table I would:

- use `tabularx` table environment
- remove all vertical lines
- for horizontal lines use rules defined in `booktabs` package
- for columns with `min`, `max` values make comon column hears

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \small
    \setcellgapes{1pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} l *{10}{C} @{} }
    \toprule
        & \mcc[10]{Factor level}        \\
    \cmidrule{2-11}
Output  &   \multirow{2.8}{=}{ABS-UTS}
            &   \mcc[2]{ABS-THETA}  
                &   \mcc[2]{ABS-Sa}
                    &   \multirow{2.8}{=}{PLA-UTS}
                        &   \mcc[2]{PLA-THETA}
                            &   \mcc[2]{PLA-Sa}                 \\
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}\cmidrule(l){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
        &   & min & max & min & max &   & min & max & min & max \\
    \midrule
Nozzle temperature (\si{celsius})
        & 3 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
Deposition speed  (\si{mm\per\second})
        &   3 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
Layer heigh (\si{\milli\metre}) 
        & 3 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Configurations for single lap experimental investigation}
        \label{tab:results}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great, thank you! You're probably right, I was searching in the log trying to find errors for a long time without any solution.