# Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) with Tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx, unit-of-measure

I am working on a journal paper using the Overleaf website to compile it.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t]
\caption{tabmle1}
\label{tab2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Dataset} &  \textbf{Metrics} & \textbf{algo1} & \textbf{algo2}  \\ \cline{1-4}
\multirow{4}{4} {data1} & M1 & 5.36778  & 6.20198 \\ \cline{2-4}
& M2 & 5.16952 & 3.78941     \\ \cline{2-4}

& M3 & 8.92139  & 9.63108  \\ \cline{2-4}

&M4 & 0.07484 & - 1.16580  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\hline
\multirow{4}{4}{data2} & M1& 2.02522 &  6.48972 \\ \cline{2-4}
& M2 & 6.15882 &    9.69980 \\ \cline{2-4}

& M3 & 8.12485  & 8.68411  \\ \cline{2-4}

& M4& -1.16187 & - 11.55713  \\ \cline{1-4}
%\hline
\end{tabularx} 
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.33 \end{tabularx}
                   
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.
```

I am new to latex, I made some research and it [indicates](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Illegal_unit_of_measure_(pt_inserted)) that this error may occur when having a line break \\ followed by square brackets, which is not the case for this code. Other [suggests](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514946/illegal-unit-of-measure-pt-inserted-in-the-table-that-might-be-too-wide-for-th) using Tabularx, it is already the used environment.

Furthermore, I can not really understand the source of this error.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: the correct usage of  `\multirow{4}{*} {data1}` - -please see the documentation of multirow package -- I think this is the error

Comment: @jsbibra yes --- or `\multirow{4}{=} {data1}` --- otherwise the second argument must be a dimension. BTW @Abdessamad139--- `llncs` is not a standard class...

Comment: Thanks for your update @js bibra, in fact I have a very long sentence instead of "data1", using ```\multirow{4}{*} {data1}``` will make this long sentence cross the other column of the table.

Comment: @Rmano ```\multirow{4}{=} {data1}``` works fine with the long sentence, thank you.
for the ```llncs```, I am just following the journal template (Springer template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Mostly off-topic, since your problem is already solved by comments.
I would use `siunitx` packages for writing columns with numbers:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcxbf{O{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}m}
     {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table 1}
\label{tab2}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|S[table-format=-1.5]|S[table-format=-2.5]|}
    \hline
\mcxbf[|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|]{Dataset} 
    & \mcxbf{Metrics} 
            & \mcxbf{algo1} 
                        & \mcxbf{algo2}  \\ 
    \hline
\multirow{4}{=}{data1} 
    & M1    & 5.36778   &  6.20198  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M2    & 5.16952   &  3.78941  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M3    & 8.92139   &  9.63108  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M4    & 0.07484   & -1.16580  \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{=}{data2} 
    & M1    & 2.02522   &  6.48972  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M2    & 6.15882   &  9.69980  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M3    & 8.12485   &  8.68411  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & M4    & -1.16187  & -11.55713 \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
You may liked design as suggested @{Mico in his comment below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcxbf{O{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}m}
     {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mlxbf{O{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}m}
     {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\textbf{#2}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Table 1}
\label{tab2}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX S[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=-2.5]}
    \toprule
\mlxbf{Dataset} 
    & \mlxbf{Metrics} 
            & \mcxbf{algo1} 
                        & \mcxbf{algo2}  \\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{=}{data1} 
    & M1    & 5.36778   &  6.20198  \\ 
    & M2    & 5.16952   &  3.78941  \\ 
    & M3    & 8.92139   &  9.63108  \\ 
    & M4    & 0.07484   & -1.16580  \\
    \midrule
\multirow{4}{=}{data2} 
    & M1    & 2.02522   &  6.48972  \\ 
    & M2    & 6.15882   &  9.69980  \\ 
    & M3    & 8.12485   &  8.68411  \\ 
    & M4    & -1.16187  & -11.55713 \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I would futher like to suggest loading the `booktabs` package, omitting the `\cline` directives, and replacing `\hline` with `\toprule, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` as appropriate.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Your suggestion is considered in addendum to answer.